# How to create an encryption/decryption function using indexes?

Tags: python, indexing

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours now and I have no idea how. I am not going to write down the problem, only the part I am struggling with.

Let's say we have:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
key = 'guwyrmqpsaeicbnozlfhdkjxtvGUWYRMQPSAEICBNOZLFHDKJXTV'
message = 'wncodhrlf'
```

As you can see, w in the message is equivalent to c, n is to o etc so the message spells out 'computer'. I need to define functions that can decode/encrypt a message using a random key, and I have been told that this is solved through indexes.

If you have any idea how to solve this please tell me. I do not need you to write a code, I simply need to be directed to a solution because I keep getting lost. Thank you for your time.

Comment: *"As you can see"* - Hmm, I don't.

Comment: Are you aware of `zip` and `dict`? `letters` is also missing "wW".

Comment: @Reti43 I know dict. I have not learned zip and I'm not supposed to use materials we haven't learned in class. I am sorry about the wW I'm editing that now

Answer (score 2):

Simple translation:

```
>>> message.translate(str.maketrans(key, letters))
'computers'
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to access each individual letter of the message.  One possible way is with indexes:

```python
value = message[0]
```

From there, you need to see where in the key this letter is.  String objects in Python have several helper methods.

```python
index = key.index("a")  # Finds 9 as the index
```

And now you have an index, finding the corresponding value in the list of letters is as simple as using an index:

```python
decoded = letters[9]  # Finds "j" in the list of letters
```

I'll leave it to you to piece this together.

I will note that many of these could have been found in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html), it's quite approachable, I recommend trying to read through it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the actual letter and the encrypted letter have the same index in the letters and key variables respectively.

So to parse an encrypted string, you can just loop through the letters of the string, find each character's index in the key string, then get the letter at that index in the letters string.

For example, calling key.index('w') should return 2. Calling letters[2] will then return 'c'.

To encrypt an unencrypted string, you just do the opposite. E.g. to encrypt the 'c', call letters.index('c'), which returns 2. Then calling key[2] should return 'w'.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit Python code using dictionary:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
key = 'guwyrmqpsaeicbnozlfhdkjxtvGUWYRMQPSAEICBNOZLFHDKJXTV'
message = 'wncodhrlf'

assert len(letters) == len(key)

key_letter_mapping = {}

for i in range(len(key)):
  key_letter_mapping[key[i]] = letters[i]


result = ''
for c in message:
  result += key_letter_mapping[c]

print(result)
```